# How to make readonly structs XML serializable?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, c#-7.2

I have an immutable struct with only one field:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    private readonly double number;

    public MyStruct(double number)
        => this.number = number;
}
```

And I want this to be able to get serialized/deserialized by:

- Data contract serializer
- Binary formatter
- XML serializer (edit: forgotten in the original question)
- Json.NET (without adding Json.NET as a dependency)

So the struct becomes this:

```
[Serializable]
struct MyStruct : ISerializable, IXmlSerializable
{
    private readonly double number;

    public MyStruct(double number)
        => this.number = number;

    private MyStruct(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        => this.number = info.GetDouble(nameof(this.number));

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        => info.AddValue(nameof(this.number), this.number);

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema() => null;

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // Necessary evil
        reader.Read();
        this = new MyStruct(double.Parse(reader.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        => writer.WriteString(this.number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Because:

- `[Serializable]` is required by the binary formatter.
- Json.NET honors both `[DataContract]` and `ISerializable`.
- `[DataContract]` and `ISerializable` can't be used together.
- Luckily, `IXmlSerializer` is supported by the data contract serializer.

C# 7.2 introduces the `readonly` modifier for structs and MyStruct, being an immutable struct seems like an ideal candidate for this.

The problem is that `IXmlSerializable` interface requires the ability to mutate `MyStruct`. That's what we did above, assigning to `this` in `IXmlSerializable.ReadXml` implementation.

```
readonly struct MyStruct : IXmlSerializable
{
    // ...
    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // No longer works since "this" is now readonly.
        reader.Read();
        this = new MyStruct(double.Parse(reader.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
    // ...
}
```

I tried cheating via reflection but `FieldInfo.SetValue` boxes the value, and `FieldInfo.SetValueDirect` requires a `TypedReference`, which I can't obtain since `__makeref` is also forbidden when `this` is read-only.

So what are ways that would allow MyStruct to get serialized by the XML serializer?

I should also mention that I do not care what the output XML looks like, I don't really need the fine grained control provided by the `IXmlSerializable` interface. I only need to make MyClass consistently serializable using the serializers I listed.

Comment: How's that "[DataContract] and [Serializable] can't be used together"? They can.

Comment: The problem is these interface based serialization methods have to first have an object, which they get a specific interface from, before calling that interface. They don't call a specific constructor, which is the only place to change a `readonly` field. They were envisioned before immutable types were a thing in OOP. Another option is to have set/get fields, with a private field that signals whether the object is writable & raises an exception.

Comment: @Evk `DataContractSerializer` throws an `InvalidDataContractException` when you try to serialize an object that is both marked with `[DataContract]` and implements `ISerializable`.

Comment: Maybe, but your claim is different: that `[DataContract]` and `[Serializable]` (attribute, not `ISerializable` interface) cannot be used together, while they can.

Comment: @AshleyPillay Exactly. In times like this, I wish that the XML serializer would cheat like the binary formatter and data contract serializer by creating an uninitialized object...

Comment: @Evk, you have a point, I'm updating the question.

Comment: This might be irrelevant to the question but why would you even want such a struct in the first place? Why not simply use a `double`?

Comment: Is `IXmlSerializable` required to implement? I mean it's not needed to achieve requirements listed. Or that is needed for other purposes?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I don't, it's a sample to simplify the question.

Comment: Something that may give you some mileage, instead of `private readonly` fields with a `public` property accessor, just use a `public readonly` field

Comment: @AshleyPillay I don't expose the object publicly, I only use it internally.

Comment: XML deserialization simply copies the values from the XML to your struct. You should be able to add a `static` method for deserializing your struct, but it means all deserializations must go through it instead of normal deserialization.

Comment: @Evk, I failed to get MyStruct serialized/deserialized correctly using XmlSerializer without implementing IXmlSerializable. I would appreciate an answer if you can provide the listed requirements with a readonly struct.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I know but I require XmlSerializer to work.

Comment: I didn't try it but what if you use a static method to do the actual deserialization, and also implement `IXmlSerializable` (where the `ReadXml` method simply calls the static one)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, `ReadXml` method does not return a new instance, it mutates the current one.

Comment: @ŞafakGür oops, correct. Failed to notice that. anyway I see that you got your answer so that's good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To satisfy your requirements all you need is:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public readonly struct MyStruct {
    [DataMember]
    private readonly double number;

    public MyStruct(double number)
        => this.number = number;
}
```

Test code:

```
var target = new MyStruct(2);
// with Data Contract serializer
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    var s = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyStruct));
    s.WriteObject(ms, target);
    ms.Position = 0;
    var back = (MyStruct) s.ReadObject(ms);
    Debug.Assert(target.Equals(back));
}

// with Json.NET
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(target);
var jsonBack = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyStruct>(json);
Debug.Assert(target.Equals(jsonBack));

// with binary formatter
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(ms, target);
    ms.Position = 0;
    var back = (MyStruct) formatter.Deserialize(ms);
    Debug.Assert(target.Equals(back));
}
```

Update. Since you also need to support `XmlSerializer`, you can use some unsafe code to achieve your requirements:

```
[Serializable]    
public readonly struct MyStruct : ISerializable, IXmlSerializable
{        
    private readonly double number;
    public MyStruct(double number)
        => this.number = number;

    private MyStruct(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        => this.number = info.GetDouble(nameof(this.number));

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema() {
        return null;
    }

    unsafe void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
        if (reader.Read()) {
            var value = double.Parse(reader.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            fixed (MyStruct* t = &this) {
                *t = new MyStruct(value);
            }
        }
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {
        writer.WriteString(this.number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        info.AddValue(nameof(number), this.number);
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is the XmlSerializer?

Comment: @ŞafakGür well it is not listed in " I want this to be able to get serialized/deserialized by" list.

Comment: Oh you are right once again, I apologize for forgetting it, I'm not usually this sloppy but I really thought I asked.

Comment: I'm editing the question to include it but I'll accept this answer if no one comes up with one supporting the XML serializer. Sorry for your time again.

Comment: @ŞafakGür I've updated answer with one way to achieve that. Hopefully you won't tell now that unsafe is also forbidden :)

Comment: Devilishly brilliant. :D And no, I think I caused you enough pain for today.

Comment: I accepted the answer but I wonder what would you do if the field was of a reference type like string or if it was generic? - `readonly struct MyStruct<T> { private readonly T field; }` - Will you indulge? ;)

Comment: @ŞafakGür well in that case I'm not sure how to do that unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

As a last resort, the readonliness can be "cast away" via `Unsafe.AsRef` from https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe

Assuming you you are ok with limited use of unsafe code, casting away readonliness is a bit nicer than `fixed` and can work with managed types.

The "almost immutable" struct is a known problem. It is a relatively rare case for which there is no nice and safe solution right now.

Adding a language feature that would allow selectively making only *some* members of a struct readonly is one of the proposed long-term solutions.

Answer (score 4):

While you can successfully use `unsafe`, `Unsafe.AsRef`, or `FieldInfo.SetValue` to mutate the value in some scenarios, this is technically invalid code and may result in undefined behavior.

From ECMA-335:

> [*Note:* The use of `ldflda` or `ldsflda` on an **initonly** field makes code unverifiable. In unverifiable code, the VES need not check whether **initonly** fields are mutated outside the constructors. The VES need not report any errors if a method changes the value of a constant. However, such code is not valid. *end note*]

Likewise from the official API Docs for `FieldInfo.SetValue`:

> This method cannot be used to set values of static, init-only (`readonly` in C#) fields reliably. In .NET Core 3.0 and later versions, an exception is thrown if you attempt to set a value on a static, init-only field.

The runtime is technically free to make optimizations around `initonly` fields and currently does in the case of certain `static, initonly` fields.

You might be interested in the new `init only setters` feature coming in C# 9 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#init-only-setters). This provides a valid way to set properties as part of the property initializer syntax and will get the appropriate support/changes to ensure they work successfully and result in valid code.